# AppEngine real time querying - cost, performance, latency balancing act and quotas

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, task-queue

I am trying to design an app that uses Google AppEngine to store/process/query data that is then served up to mobile devices via Cloud Endpoints API in as real time as possible.

It is straight forward enough solution, however I am struggling to get the right balance between, performance, cost and latency on AppEngine.

Scenario (analogy) is a user checks-in (many times per day from different locations, cities, countries), and we would like to allow the user to query all the data via their device and provide as up to date information as possible.

- Such as:

  - The number of check-ins over the last:
  - 24 hours
  - 1 week
  - 1 month
  - All time
  - Where is the most checked in place/city/country over the same time periods
  - Where is the least checked in place over the same time periods
  - Other similar querying reports

We can use Memcache to store the most recent checkins, pushing to the Datastore every 5 minutes, but this may not scale very well and is not robust!
Use a Cron job to run the Task Queue/Map Reduce to get the aggregates, averages for each location every 30 mins and update the Datastore.

The challenge is to use as little read/writes over the datastore because the last "24 hours" data is changing every 5 mins, and hence so is the last weeks data, last months data and so on. The data has to be dynamic to some degree, so it is not fixed points in time, they are always changing - here in lies the issue!

It is not a problem to set this up, but to set it up in an efficient manner, balancing performance/latency for the user and cost/quotas for us is not so easy!

The simple solution would be to use SQL, and run date range queries but this will not scale very well.

We could eventually use BigTable & BigQuery for the "All time" time period querying, but in order to give the users as real-time as possible data via the API for the other time periods is proving quite the challenge!

Any suggestions of AppEngine architecture/approaches would be seriously welcomed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Push Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) is more robust than Memcache for adding new check-ins.  [Memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/) together with [get_entity_group_version(key)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata) reduces read volumes.

Aggregate statistical data (for example most and least popular locations) ahead of time from user history over daily, weekly, monthly and yearly dimensions to reduce query record counts (same as analysis databases do).  Design your real time queries so as to merge stored aggregate data from the past with the small amount of current data that you have not yet aggregated.

Comment: Thanks very much Martin for the suggestions and links, really appreciate it, some good points there, will look into them.

Answer (score 0):

First, writes to the datastore take milliseconds. By the time your user hits the refresh button (or whatever you offer), the data will be as "real-time" as it gets.

Typically, developers become concerned with real-time when there is a synchronization/congestion issue, i.e. each user can update something (e.g. bid on an item), and all users have to get the same data (the highest bid) in real time. In your case, what's the harm if a user gets the number of check-ins which is 1 second old?

Second, data in Memcache can be lost at any moment. In your proposed solution (update the datastore every 5 minutes), you risk losing all data for the 5 min period.

I would rather use Memcache in the opposite direction: read data from datastore, put it in Memcache with 60 seconds (or more) expiration, serve all users from Memcache, then refresh it. This will minimize your reads. I would do it, of course, unless your users absolutely must know how many checkins happened in the last 60 seconds.

The real question for you is how to model your data to optimize writes. If you don't want to lose data, you will have to record every checkin in datastore. You can save by making sure you don't have unnecessary indexed fields, separate out frequently updated fields from the rest, etc.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for the feedback, you make some good points and tend to agree with you on most of them - what would you think about pushing a text file to the users device with global data on it, so when they do query that side of things, they do the number crunching via their device? Then we push a new updated file every 30 minutes - very different I know to the real time approach, but just a thought - is it stupid?

Comment: I am not sure how scalable this approach is. As the volume of data grows, the file size will grow, and the processing time will grow exponentially. With the datastore you have a guaranteed performance.

Comment: Also Andrei, how did you mean exactly when you said "separate out frequently updated fields from the rest" - do you mean normalise the data? Or so there is no need for custom indexes?

Comment: Fewer indexes is good, but the key benefit is the write costs. Every time you update an entity, you have to re-write every property. For indexed properties that means extra cost. So if you have a user record, for example, fields like name, date of birth, status, email, etc. do not change frequently, while a field like "points" may change every few minutes. In this case you want to put the "points" property into a separate entity to reduce the write costs.

Comment: Makes sense Andrei, thanks for clarifying. 
I know you mentioned to possibly use Memcache in the opposite way as to how I suggested, which again makes complete sense, I was wondering have you ever heard of [link](https://github.com/gregbayer/gae-livecount)Livecount from Pulse? That's what gave me the ideas, so was going to possibly try that?